# API for a company's financial profile

Tags: finance

I am looking for an API that will allow me to ultimately find financial profile information about a company, particularly revenue per employee. Also, need the API to produce a list of all companies for which such information exists.

I do see many APIs that provide stock trading activity. But, I am need more in terms of fundamentals, e.g. gross, operating and net margin and as mentioned above revenue per employee.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, that all this information you will be able to find in one API.
I think you can try to use this API to receive detailed info about company: https://data.crunchbase.com/docs/getting-started

And financial info you can find in Yahoo API https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/key-statistics?p=GOOG

Comment: Thanks!

I see the the Google URL above calls the web page. I do wonder how to access this information via the API. I looked around the API for a bit, could not find revenue per employee. Let me look more.